# Waiting on API response before deleting from SQLite DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite

I am having trouble coming up with an efficient way of deleting information from a SQLite DB after a JSON response.

Basically how what I am trying to do is:

I have a DB with 100 records.

1. I read the first record
2. Build a JSON package and send it to my API.
3. WAIT for the API to respond Ok or Fail
4. The delete the record from the DB on OK.
5. Move to the next record.

There is some time between waiting on a response before I can delete and go on.

[image]

A simple *FOR* doesn't seem to work as it can't wait for the 'OK' from the API.

I looked into `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue());` but if the OK comes and the DB is processing it will lock the DB while it is being accessed and the logic fails because the db is locked.

I need a mixture of the two. Does anyone know of a tutorial or where to start with something like this?

Comment: Are you going to loop through the 100 records, asking the remote service "can I delete this one?" - waiting for a response each time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Use blocks  to receive async response, and perform sqlite operations in the block when you receive the response.

Comment: I tried that with the `dispatch_async queue` it would just create multiple instances and lock the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use an operation queue and your own custom operation. Setup the operation queue to be serial or set it to allow some small number of concurrent operations.

Loop through each record creating an operation for each record. Put each operation on the queue.

The implementation of the operation will be to make the API call and then delete the one record if that API call indicates it should be deleted. Ensure that the operation's `main` doesn't reach its end until the API call is complete.

Comment: Using `nsoperationqueue` would help me accomplish this?

Comment: I am not using Swift yet. Still Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, `NSOperatationQueue` and `NSOperation`.

Comment: Any chance that once I have written it, I could bounce it off you to see if I did it properly?

Comment: You can post a new question with relevant code clearly explaining whatever issue you may be having, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array where you will hold temporarily your data to delete

```
NSMutableArray* itemsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

Once you received a response with success you append the items to be deleted to this array. do the same process in all calls with success. once your done with uploading your data at your last response of success or failure check your itemsToDelete array inside a for loop and delete everything from your DB

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks changed the line of code from swift to objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using blocks to receive the response from async calls. In that case, you can perform the DB operation within the block.

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue());` is not for the async calls. It is mostly used to update the UI.

All the async calls needs to be done on background thread.

Coming to your problem, you can do something like this:

```
-(void)checkToDeleteWithCompletion:(MyCompletion)completion{

    __block NSMutableArray *responseArray =  [NSMutableArray array];

  // Create a dispatch group
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.count; i++) {
        // Enter the group for each request we create
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

            [self ..methodToPErformAsynccallWithCOmpleton success:^(BOOL success, id response) {
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
                 [responseArray addObject:response];

            } failure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            }];
     }

    // Here we wait for all the requests to finish
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do whatever you need to do when all requests are finished
        completion(YES,[responseArray copy]);
    });
}
```

And finally you can use a for loop on responseArray, to delete the unwanted objects.

You can also limit the number of concurrent calls by using :

```
dispatch_semaphore_create(maxConcurrencyValue)
```

Or you can use NSOperation as suggested by rmaddy!

Comment: There's a serious flaw with this approach  - you end up making `yourArray.count` concurrent requests to the API. That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: As far as I know we cannot create N completion blocks for N async api calls. @rmaddy . If you know a better way on handling this, please guide me! Thanks! I end up with this after trying some horrible ways lol!

Comment: See my answer for a better way (at least better at ensuring only a limited number of concurrent API calls).